# getting net.sf.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, json, interface

i have the following method

```
public static <E> APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent generateResponse(E request, E response, int statusCode){

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        result.put(Constants.REQUEST, request);
        result.put(Constants.RESPONSE, response);

        return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                .withBody(result.toString())
                .withStatusCode(statusCode)
                .withHeaders(Constants.commonHeaders);
    }
```

i am getting `net.sf.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` when `result.put(Constants.RESPONSE, response);` is executed

response is

[image]

Also the corresponding class is:

```
    public class PhysicalMediaURL extends MediaURL {
        private static final String IDENTIFIER_PREFIX = "images/I/";
    
        public PhysicalMediaURL(String physicalId, String extension, MediaHostnameProvider mediaHostnameProvider) {
            super("images/I/" + physicalId, extension, mediaHostnameProvider);
        }
    }

public abstract class MediaURL implements URL {
    private final String identifier;
    private final String extension;
    private final MediaHostnameProvider mediaHostnameProvider;

    public MediaURL(String identifier, String extension, MediaHostnameProvider mediaHostnameProvider) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.extension = extension;
        this.mediaHostnameProvider = mediaHostnameProvider;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return this.identifier;
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return this.extension;
    }

    public String getDomainName() {
        return this.mediaHostnameProvider.getMediaHostname(this.getExtension());
    }

    public String getURL() {
        StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        urlBuilder.append("https://");
        urlBuilder.append(this.getDomainName());
        urlBuilder.append('/');
        urlBuilder.append(this.getIdentifier());
        urlBuilder.append('.');
        urlBuilder.append(this.getExtension());
        return urlBuilder.toString();
    }

    public List<String> getStyleTags() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

where PhysicalMediaURL is of type: URL and that is an interface

```
public interface URL {
    String getIdentifier();

    String getDomainName();

    String getExtension();

    List<String> getStyleTags();

    String getURL();
}
```

I am a bit stuck in this.. need help.

Answer (score 0):

First off it looks like you are using a JSON implementation that is not updated as regularly as the other ones(Your exception is from net.sf.json). I always recommend using the org.json implementation as it receives regular updates and bugfixes.

Most implementations of JSONObject, when used in this form, use bean based reflection to retrieve values from your object.  This is not always what you want when your object is in an inheritance hierarchy because, depending on the object and the JSONObject impl, it will pull fields from the implementation that are not on your higher level type(URL in this case).

If you really want a generic serialization function use something like Jackson or Gson that will allow you to specify the type as a part of the serialization. Otherwise consider transforming your objects, before they are passed to your generateResponse function, into simpler objects such as a Map<String, String> that can serialize unambiguously.

As a final thought JSONObject's generic serialization works, but, its performance is likely to be worse than using a dedicated higher level serializer like Jackson. It's best used with the explicit put methods to generate simple objects.